# Issue in compareTo method

Tags: java

Getting below bug in findbug:
EQ_COMPARETO_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS
Below is the statement:

```
public int compareTo (OPVest vesting)
{
int c = this.Date.compareTo (vest.Date);
if (c != 0)
return c;

return this.Id - vest.segmentId;
}
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What bug? I suggest you update to provide an example of your inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

from [java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29)

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that
>   (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class
>   that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition
>   should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note:
>   this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

override `equals` - and `hashCode`

and you have some errors in code

```
 public int compareTo (OPVest vesting)
   {
      int c = this.Date.compareTo (vesting.Date);
       if (c != 0)
         return c;

        return this.Id - vesting.segmentId;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically FindBugs is complaining about the fact that [your compareTo() method is inconsistent with equals()](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#EQ_COMPARETO_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS).

Your compareTo method should return zero, only if `this` equals the operand.

Possible fixes are :

- Overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` to be in line with what your `compareTo()` method does.
- Using a `Comparator` rather than making this class `Comparable`, and documenting it to be inconsistent with `equals()`
- Document this class to have a natural ordering that is inconsistent with `equals()`. I guess this won't make FindBugs happy, but it is a valid, yet discouraged, possibility.

As a side remark : be sure that if you return the result of an addition or substraction for `compareTo()` that you cannot get an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the value of `compareTo()` should return zero if and only if `equals()` returns true. Failure to meet this, may cause unpredictable behaviour in other Java classes. Since the default `equals()` method uses different criteria to compare objects, be sure to override `equals()` if you override `compareTo()`.